# Magento 2 minicart

Tags: magento-2.1.3, quantity, mini-cart

I'm Using magento 2.1.3 and i face a problem regarding minicart when there is no item in the minicart its showing only the value **"0"** and the **label items** was not displaying

After adding a product the product quantity showing multiple time that is if i add 1 product its showing like this  **"11" items**   and here i can see the label items

Here is my minicart.phtml file

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Here is content.html file

```
    <!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="block-title">
    <strong>
        <span class="text"><!-- ko i18n: 'My Cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <span
            class="qty empty"
            data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false },
                       attr: { title: $t('Items in Cart') }">
            <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </strong>
</div>

<div class="block-content">
    <button type="button"
            id="btn-minicart-close"
            class="action close"
            data-action="close"
            data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }">
        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><!-- /ko --></span>
    </button>

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <div class="items-total">
            <span class="count"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>

        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('extraInfo') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') -->
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="primary">
                <button
                        id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                        type="button"
                        class="action primary checkout"
                        data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Go to Checkout')}">
                    <!-- ko i18n: 'Go to Checkout' --><!-- /ko -->
                </button>
                <div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Recently added item(s)' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
    <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
        <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartParam('items'), as: 'item' }">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ol>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko ifnot: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
        <strong class="subtitle empty" data-bind="visible: closeSidebar()">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' --><!-- /ko -->
        </strong>
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') -->
            <p class="minicart empty text"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('cart_empty_message') --><!-- /ko --></p>

            <div class="actions">
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                        <span><!-- ko text: $t('View and edit cart') --><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                <span><!-- ko i18n: 'View and edit cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <div id="minicart-widgets" class="minicart-widgets">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('promotion') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('sign-in-popup') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: please show your phtml code to more debug

Comment: @ Rakesh Jesadiya please check the code